# Use $this in function callback in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to set `$this` in PHP inside a function?

**Something like this:**

```
$container = new \Container();

$a = function(){
    print_r($this);
};

$a->bindTo($container,"\Container");

$a();
```

I used `bindTo()` function, but have gotten a very descriptive error:

```
Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /index.php
```

Is there a way around this?

I am asking because it would be very convenient to pass values using `$this` inside middleware and API endpoint functions.

Comment: you cant use $this outside the class

Comment: Why not explicitly pass the object you want to modify as function argument? Using `$this` implicitly instead of a function parameter explicitly doesn’t really have any advantage, does it?

Comment: I find the syntax of callback clearer. Would not use it in any other scenario than API end points

Comment: or maybe some weird framework mumbojumbo

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, my bad. `bindTo()` returns a new function

```
$a = $a->bindTo($container,"\Container");
```

is the way to go.